# Borna Active Directory Manager doesn't work (HTTP 500.19 Error)

Tags: http-error, iis-10

After I installed Borna Active Directory manager in Windows Server 2016, I got the following error:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
Module: IIS Web Core 
Notification: BeginRequest 
Error Code: 0x80070021 
Requested URL: http://localhost:7070/borna 
Config Source:
  134:      </defaultDocument>
  135:      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  136:      <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
```

How can I solve the problem? Does this problem stem from Windows Server 2016? I can install Borna AD manager on Windows Server 2008, but I prefer not to.

Answer (score 3):

I had the problem too. In windows Server 2016, go to Add Roles and Features, in Server Role section, go to Web Server (IIS)> Web Server > Application Development and check ASP.NET 4.6. Note that some other features will be automatically checked. Install them and problem will be solved. 
Note that in the installation guide, they have mentioned to check some other features as well. So, if you encounter a problem see the installation guide. In my case, that was enough.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for Server 2016.